# Lookup values of a give dataframe by a series of index?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm constructing a house price forecasting model, suppose I have a DataFrame df on average house prices of various districts in Beijing. I get it from my training set.

```
>>>df
>>>df
         price
area
Haidian  80448
Xicheng  113698
Chaoyang 66424
...
```

Now how can I lookup prices just by a pandas Series object? Let's say it's

```
0                         Xicheng
1                         Haidian
2                       Dongcheng
3                        Chaoyang
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: show your implimentation. then only we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), if necessary add [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':[80448, 113698, 66424]}, index=['Haidian', 'Xicheng', 'Chaoyang'])
df.index.name = 'area'
print (df)
           price
area            
Haidian    80448
Xicheng   113698
Chaoyang   66424

s = pd.Series(['Xicheng','Haidian','Dongcheng','Chaoyang'])
print (s)
0      Xicheng
1      Haidian
2    Dongcheng
3     Chaoyang
dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df.loc[s])
              price
area               
Xicheng    113698.0
Haidian     80448.0
Dongcheng       NaN
Chaoyang    66424.0

print (df.loc[df.index.intersection(s)])
           price
Xicheng   113698
Haidian    80448
Chaoyang   66424
```